# How to override Pyqt combobox ItemText method so it returns default python string instead of QString?

Tags: python, list, combobox, pyqt, pyqt4

When ever I do

```
resos = [_ui.ComboBox.itemText(i) for i in range(_ui.ComboBox.count())]
```

it is giving me list of

```
[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'1280x720 from 1.316'),
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'1920x1080 from 1.316'),]
```

how would it be possible to override ComboBox's itemText method so that it only returns python string ? instead of doing string conversion in the list comprehension above !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just subclass `QComboBox`:

```
class MyComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def itemText(self, index):
        return str(super(MyComboBox, self).itemText(index))
```

Note however that you may run into trouble if your combobox contains non-Ascii characters.

Or you could try monkey-patching, but that is just plain ugly:

```
def foo(combo):
    def wrapper(index):
        return str(QtGui.QComboBox.itemText(combo, index))
    return wrapper

_ui.ComboBox.itemText = foo(_ui.ComboBox)
```

Comment: In Python2, you should always use `unicode()` to convert `QString`.

Comment: @ekhumoro why not string ?

Comment: @san. Because in Python2, `str()` returns bytes, so if the `QString` contains non-ascii characters, it will raise a `UnicodeEncodeError`. But really, the best solution is to eliminate the problem altogether and take the advice given in @three-pineapples answer. This will also make it much easier to port to Python3 when the time comes to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider importing `sip` and changing the API used for `QString`. Setting the API version to v2 disables `QString` and PyQt methods will return python unicode strings instead.

This is covered in the [PyQt4 Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html), but the short of it is:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore

# This will raise an attribute exception because QString is only wrapped
# in version 1 of the API.
s = QtCore.QString()
```

As `QtCore.QString` doesn't exist, you will get native Python types from methods that usually return a `QString`.

Note, it is often useful to change the API for `QVariant` as well, particularly if dealing with models in PyQt, to avoid having to typecast to Python types.